# How is mapTo more efficient than map in Scalding

Tags: scala, scalding

The Scalding reference on Github (https://github.com/twitter/scalding/wiki/Fields-based-API-Reference#map-functions) says the following:

> MapTo is equivalent to mapping and then projecting to the new fields, but is more efficient. Thus, the  following two lines produce the same result:
>
> `pipe.mapTo(existingFields -> additionalFields){ ... } 
>   pipe.map(existingFields -> additionalFields){ ... }.project(additionalFields)`

My question is:

- How is mapTo more efficient than map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you indicate which fields are remaining, there is no need to keep the fields that are going to be discarding along the way when doing the `map` operation.

Depending on the number of fields discarded and on the volume of data, the difference can be highly noticeable.